# schtasks onidle only triggers once

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to trigger a task whenever the computer goes idle. I need to do this in an install package, so I am using schtasks. I am able to create a task, but it only triggers once. I am expecting it to trigger again the next time the computer enters the idle state. Here is my code:

```
schtasks /create /tn "My Task Name" /tr "My Task To Run" /sc onidle /i 1 /ru SYSTEM
```

The task triggers and runs properly one time. What am I missing to get it to run again when the computer goes idle?
Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: After the task fires, if you look at the properties of the task within Task Scheduler is there any hint about why it doesn't fire again, such as the task no longer being marked as "enabled" or an expire time being set?

Comment: The task is always marked as enabled. I don't see an 'expire time' anywhere. FWIW this is on a Server 2012 R2 VM. Seems to work once more if I reboot. Have never seen it run twice w/o reboot.